# MySQL - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean, mysql-5.5

First, We are trying to updating our password for phpmyadmin. We tried different methods like in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysqld_safe-can-t-log-to-error-log-and-syslog-at-the-same-time but its not successfully fixed.

Second, We tried also restarting the mysql but it won't work. I checked the status of mysql it is saying mysql stop/waiting.

Third, We tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/697805/package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet reconfiguring the mysql. But sadly it's not working.

Any help or advise? Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does the sock file exist in that /var/run/mysqld path?

If not, create it and reboot the server

Also check if your hard drive is full.